# Can external JavaScript files access their host origin without JSONP?

Tags: javascript, ajax, cors, jsonp, same-origin-policy

If I load a javascript file in my head HTML page which is not hosted in my server, like in this example:

```
<html><head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script></head>
<body>...
```

Is the script in this file authorized by the browser to make requests for the origial host (*code.jquery.com*) bypassing the same-origin-policy without the need to implement JSONP or CORS?

Comment: no, but you could use a browser plug-in to allow it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No...the request is made using the domain, port, protocol  and subdomain the page is on.

Where the scripts come from is irrelevant....they all get compiled into the current page (window)

Comment: Funny, it's very different from `iframes`, where the `window` object seems to be another...